# Access Denied Error In Post Shipment APIs

Tags: api, postman, flask-restful

I'm working on Restful API for Post shipment. When I am checking it on Postman It showing me Access Denied Error. Can Anyone Help me ?
https://api.postshipping.com/api2/tracks?ReferenceNumber=************

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCanZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read How to Ask, as well as this question checklist. Also please learn how to edit your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing a session cookie / authentication at all to access this endpoint. Please check, if there is any authentication required and if so, if the user has enough rights to access this data.

Comment: Where should I pass my iD and Passowrd in Postman ? Can you explain this ?

Comment: Depends on the api, probably there is some endpoint for authentication using e.g. url-endoding. Probably you need to create an access token via the provider first, which you then have to provide with each request. I recommend checkin the API documentation for authentication types